# Using NVL to display 'none' instead of 0

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I cannot figure out how to replace 0 with 'none'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, NVL(TO_CHAR(COUNT(e.student_id)), 'none')  AS enrollments
FROM student s
LEFT OUTER JOIN enrollment e
ON s.student_id = e.student_id
WHERE s.phone LIKE '%617%'
GROUP BY s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name
ORDER BY s.last_name, s.first_name;
```

Comment: NULL is not the same thing as the number 0. COUNT returns 0, rather than NULL. NVL replaces NULL, not the number 0. Does that help?

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace that single statement with:

`DECODE(COUNT(e.student_id), 0, 'none', COUNT(e.student_id)) AS enrollments`

What it does is it checks the count first; if there are no applicable values COUNT will return 0. Then, it will decode that to your string. If there were records, it will return the COUNT function instead.